# Issues while executing gof fuction of hydroGOF package

Tags: r, hydrogof

I received this error while running the gof function of the hydroGOF package in R. My data frames correspond to observed and simulated measurements for precipitation. Both have the same dimensions and both are free of NA values. I think it may be possible because they contain zeros, and there may be columns full of such values.
In the rows (22) are the stations to which the observations belong sorted along the columns corresponding to the dates (7671).
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
gof_total<-gof(time.serie.raster[,2:7672], time.serie.est[,2:7672])
```

`Error in if (denominator != 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I hope we can reach a solution

Comment: Hi Miguel! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be able to provide a sample of your data, and the relevant code? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example